# Accessing private attribute within the class

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

Why does the following code not work (ExtJS V6)?

```
Ext.define('Test', {
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
xtype: 'basic-window',

config: {
    mytitle: ''
},

constructor: function (config) {
    Ext.apply(this, config);
    this.callParent(config);
},

requires: [
           'Ext.form.Panel'
       ],

height: 300,
width: 400,
scope: this, 
title: 'title: ' + this.mytitle,
autoScroll: true,
autoShow: true,
bodyPadding: 10,
html: "Lorem ipsum",
constrain: true,
});

var t = Ext.create('Test', {mytitle: 'testtitle'});
t.show();
```

I would expect that this sets the title of the window to "title: testtitle". Instead, it sets the title to "title: undefined".

Add-on: if i use

```
...
title: 'title' + this.getMytitle(),
...
```

I get "Uncaught TypeError: this.getMytitle is not a function". Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First Problem**
When `title: 'title: ' + this.mytitle` is evaluated, `this` does not point to an instance of your class. You should do that from the `constructor`

**Also**
The call to `callParent` expects an array of arguments, it's easier to always call `this.callParent(arguments)`

**Lastly**
You can only call `this.getMytitle()` after you've called the constructor.

See https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/uh9

```
constructor: function(config) {
    this.callParent(arguments);
    this.setTitle( 'title: ' + this.getMytitle() )                      
},
```

---

**About Configs** The correct way to do respond to a config being set

By implementing `updateMytitle`, it will also  work whenever anybody calls `setMytitle('title')`

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/uha

```
Ext.define('Test', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    xtype: 'basic-window',
    requires: ['Ext.form.Panel'],
    config: {
        mytitle: ''
    },

    updateMytitle: function(mytitle) {
        this.setTitle('title: ' + mytitle);        
    },
```

Comment: Here you can find more information about the magical getters, setters, update and apply functions: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?171113-Difference-between-update-and-apply-magic-methods&p=708489&viewfull=1#post708489